# How to get the web page to a specific web page after Laravel Jetstream authentication?

Tags: php, laravel

I installed the Jetstream authentication in my project. Now i don't know how to make the web page go to a specific page(view).

1. Route - this is my main route, here i make my website to go to the log in page, which contains the features of jetstream authentication, after user successfully register/login he/she will be brought upon the edited jetstream dashboard

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('login');
});

Route::get('/home', [HomeController::class, 'redirect']);

Route::middleware([
    'auth:sanctum',
    config('jetstream.auth_session'),
    'verified'
])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
        return view('dashboard');
    })->name('dashboard');
});
```

2. View - this is the login view, just copy n paste from the code after i installed jetstream authentication into my project

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="relative flex items-top justify-center min-h-screen bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-900 sm:items-center py-4 sm:pt-0">
        @if (Route::has('login'))
        <div class="hidden fixed top-0 right-0 px-6 py-4 sm:block">
            @auth
            <a href="{{ url('/dashboard') }}" class="text-sm text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-500 underline">Dashboard</a>
            @else
            <a href="{{ route('login') }}" class="text-sm text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-500 underline">Log in</a>

            @if (Route::has('register'))
            <a href="{{ route('register') }}" class="ml-4 text-sm text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-500 underline">Register</a>
            @endif
            @endauth
        </div>
        @endif
</body>

</html>
```

3. View - this is the homepage view after the user login they will be supposedly directed here instead of the main dashboard

```
<x-app-layout>
    <h1>User Dashboard</h1>
    <table>
        <tr>abu</tr>
    </table>
</x-app-layout>
```

4. Controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
 
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function redirect()
    {
        if (auth::id()) {
            if (auth::user()->usertype == '0') {
                return view('home');
            } else {
                return view('home');
            }
        } else {
            return redirect()->back();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add code in question instead of screenshot.

Comment: ok ive included the codes instead of screenshot